# Is there a need to reboot Cloud VPS

Tags: server, centos, cloud, digital-ocean, vps

I am running a web application on DigitalOcean VPS(CentOS 7) from almost 7-8 months and has never rebooted the VPS. I haven't seen any problem in the working or web application or database or mail server. Do I really need to reboot it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you need to reboot your server after kernel upgrades or some security patches but generally you will never need to reboot any linux distribution.